# Uploading a image or svg from the computer (macos) for flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Is there a way to upload a image or svg from the computer (macos) for a flutter web application

edit: I want to UPLOAD image from computer folder (macos or PC) to my FLUTTER WEB APP, via a UPLOAD button inside the FLUTTER WEB APP itself (i.e. in run time)!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use it as assets
like you use Custom Fonts and images after adding assets in Pubspec.yaml

Comment: I think my question was not clear. I want to UPLOAD image to my FLUTTER WEB APP, via a UPLOAD button inside the FLUTTER WEB APP itself! Any suggestions?

Comment: Ohh Sorry!! Now got your question . Here is the package to use : https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker . You can specify here which file type to be picked .



`Pick files using custom format filtering — you can provide a list of file extensions (pdf, svg, zip, etc.)
`

Comment: Glad to know that my answer helped . Can u please mark my question as helpful so that i can get few reputation score